# Building Sphinx documentation with Breathe, Exhale and Doxygen gives XML error

Tags: xml, python-sphinx, doxygen, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I am trying to set up the documentation for my C++/Python library, and want to use Sphinx and Read The Docs to do so. Because a large portion of the library will be written in C++, I have to use something like Breathe and Doxygen to access the C++ docstrings that are provided.

When building the documentation on my computer (`make html`), everything works perfectly and I get the documentation as expected, however, when I try to build the documentation using Read The Docs, the build fails with an XML error:

```
breathe.parser.ParserError:
file /home/docs <a load of directories> /doxygenoutput/xml/classndarray_1_1basic__extent.xml:
not well-formed (invalid token): line 13, column 33
```

I've checked the file that is being complained about, and line 13 doesn't even have 33 columns, so my only assumption is that something different is being done with the build process.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

In case it helps, here are the versions of software I'm using:

```
Sphinx: 3.4.3
breathe: 4.30.0
exhale: 0.2.3
doxygen: 1.9.1 <== (EDIT -- installed version 1.8.13, which is the version on RTD)
```

============ EDIT ============

Here are the first 40 lines of the file `classndarray_1_1basic__extent.xml` that are generated by doxygen. It would appear that this version of doxygen doesn't like templated functions?

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<doxygen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="compound.xsd" version="1.8.13">
  <compounddef id="classndarray_1_1basic__extent" kind="class" language="C++" prot="public">
    <compoundname>ndarray::basic_extent</compoundname>
    <templateparamlist>
      <param>
        <type>typename</type>
        <declname>T</declname>
        <defname>T</defname>
      </param>
      <param>
        <type>typename</type>
        <declname>std::enable_if< std::is_integral< T >::value, int >::type</declname> <<<<<<<< This is line 13
        <defname>std::enable_if< std::is_integral< T >::value, int >::type</defname>
        <defval>0</defval>
      </param>
    </templateparamlist>
      <sectiondef kind="private-attrib">
      <memberdef kind="variable" id="classndarray_1_1basic__extent_1a4e3d7dc85fd368dfcc46750ca908322f" prot="private" static="no" mutable="no">
        <type>T</type>
        <definition>T ndarray::basic_extent&lt; T, type &gt;::m_extent[50]</definition>
        <argsstring>[50]</argsstring>
        <name>m_extent</name>
        <initializer>{}</initializer>
        <briefdescription>
        </briefdescription>
        <detaileddescription>
        </detaileddescription>
        <inbodydescription>
        </inbodydescription>
        <location file="project dir/ndarray/basic_extent.hpp" line="218" column="1" bodyfile="project dir/ndarray/basic_extent.hpp" bodystart="218" bodyend="-1"/>
      </memberdef>
      <memberdef kind="variable" id="classndarray_1_1basic__extent_1ab050b78051726f3bfedad2b793f49d24" prot="private" static="no" mutable="no">
        <type>T</type>
        <definition>T ndarray::basic_extent&lt; T, type &gt;::m_extent_alt[50]</definition>
        <argsstring>[50]</argsstring>
        <name>m_extent_alt</name>
        <initializer>{}</initializer>
        <briefdescription>
        </briefdescription>
```

In line 13 (noted above) it appears that doxygen is complaining about the `<` of the templated function.

Comment: What is the size of the file classndarray_1_1basic__extent.xml? Without seeing the content the file classndarray_1_1basic__extent.xml it is hard to tell whether the file is incorrect or not (recently some fixes have been made in the generated xml file, they are available in the doxygen master from github), so please share the xml file when it is small and otherwise at least the first 40 lines (40 is a bit a random number in this case but sufficiently bigger than the mentioned numbers in the error). Based on the results from the xml file subsequent questions about settings and source can follow

Comment: @albert I've edited the question to show the file generated on my computer, but I can't access the one which is supposedly invalid on Read The Docs. Hope this helps

Comment: It might be that there is a miscount as when I look at the next line here the number of characters is 33 when not counting the initial spaces. In the snippet it is not clear why it happens (but I just asked for this part), so now we have to go a bit deeper. When you just check the xml file is this in principle well formed? What is the size of the original xml file? Can you share it? (Note when changing paths don't use `<` or `>`. Otherwise try to see if you can reduce the problem to something you can share.

Comment: I've done some more experimenting with doxygen on Read The Docs, and it's using version 1.8.13, whereas I had installed version 1.9.1, which is the latest version. Installing the older version gives me the same results as on Read The Docs (i.e. it fails), so I can update the XML snippet to hopefully show that something is wrong.

Comment: When the 1.9.1 version of doxygen is OK I don't get what you mean with / want to accomplish with "I can update the XML snippet to hopefully show that something is wrong."  The 1.8.13 is a bit older (December 2016), so it would be when Read The Docs would use a newer version of doxygen.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I wasn't particularly clear with what I meant. I updated the code snippet with what doxygen 1.8.13 outputs, which is where the error is being produced. Hopefully RTD updates the doxygen version sooner rather than later, but I guess there isn't much I can do about that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not to optimistic about the update policy of "read the docs" see https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/design/build-images.html maybe you could already switch to the ubuntu20 image (though I don't know which doxygen version is used there, looks like 1.8.17, and whether or not the problem exists in the used version there)

Comment: I believe the ubuntu20 image is not yet available, as RTD outputs "Invalid "build.image": expected one of (6.0, stable, 7.0, 2.0, 5.0, testing, latest, 4.0), got ubuntu20", though the page you linked to suggests that it will be available in the near future. Thank you for pointing out the build image options -- I wasn't aware of them!